# Build JSON Array from JSON Objects

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

I am running a loop where I am getting JSON Objects as inputs how do I append all these JSONObjects in a JSONArray?
The input is a JSONObject which contains a string based key value pair called "name" which I want to extract.

Following is what I tried, I am not able to append all of them together using the following code rather they are appearing one at a time.

```
        List<String> hoi2 = new ArrayList();

        if(input != null) {
            hoi2.add(input.getString("name"));
        }

        System.out.println(hoi2);
```

Sample input format (Getting One Input at a time):

```
{"lon":77.5858225,"name":"bingo","lat":12.9171587}
{"lon":77.5858225,"name":"dingo","lat":12.9171587}
{"lon":77.5858225,"name":"lingo","lat":12.9171587}
```

Required result:

```
["bingo","dingo","lingo"]
```

My current result:

```
["bingo"]
["dingo"]
["lingo"]
```

**Update: 
I realised the issue my approach was wrong since my array was going blank after every input and re-writing it hence had to define a global variable.**

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: please add the code along with loop, are you writing the complete given code inside a loop?

Answer (score 0):

For below code:

```
List<Integer> hoi2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            hoi2.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(hoi2);
```

Output will be:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

For below code:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            List<Integer> hoi2 = new ArrayList();
            hoi2.add(i);
            System.out.println(hoi2);
        }
```

Output will be:

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < docList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(hoi2.get(i));
            jArray.put(json);
        }
```

Comment: I am getting one input at a time

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               obj.getInt("id"));
}

Answer (score 0):

here may post complete solution please refer it.

**Code :**

```
List<String> hoi2 = new ArrayList();
hoi2.add("{\"lon\":77.5858225,\"name\":\"bingo\",\"lat\":12.9171587}");
hoi2.add("{\"lon\":77.5858225,\"name\":\"dingo\",\"lat\":12.9171587}");
hoi2.add("{\"lon\":77.5858225,\"name\":\"lingo\",\"lat\":12.9171587}");

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

try {
    for (int i = 0; i < hoi2.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(hoi2.get(i));
        System.out.print(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject.getString("name"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.print(jsonArray.toString());
```

**output :**

```
["bingo","dingo","lingo"]
```

Comment: I have String inside an array hence "JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(hoi2.get(i));" is giving an error

Comment: if possible then please add error on the comment box. @InheritedGeek

Comment: json jar added into your project?

Comment: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: which IDE you use? becuse this code perform into android studio and android give by default JSON facility so may not add import statment into this solution.

Comment: i use eclipse neon.